# How can I include CiviCRM relationships to node creations screens?

Tags: drupal-views, relationships

What I want to do is allow content authors to associate their news stories to their organisations.

I currently expose the organisations as an auto-complete field, however the target is for the author to not be able to select any organisation except their own.

I installed [Entity Reference View](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) as this appeared to be the way forward and created the following query for it

```
    SELECT civicrm_contact.id AS id, civicrm_contact.display_name AS civicrm_contact_display_name, civicrm_relationship.contact_id_b AS civicrm_relationship_contact_id_b, civicrm_relationship.relationship_type_id AS civicrm_relationship_relationship_type_id, civicrm_contact.organization_name AS civicrm_contact_organization_name
FROM 
{civicrm_contact} civicrm_contact
LEFT JOIN {civicrm_relationship} civicrm_relationship ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_relationship.contact_id_a
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_test_member_station} field_data_field_test_member_station ON civicrm_relationship.id = field_data_field_test_member_station.field_test_member_station_target_id AND (field_data_field_test_member_station.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_test_member_station.deleted = '0')
INNER JOIN {node} field_test_member_station_civicrm_relationship ON field_data_field_test_member_station.entity_id = field_test_member_station_civicrm_relationship.nid
WHERE (( (civicrm_relationship.relationship_type_id IN  ('17')) ))
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

As an Entity Reference AND as an Entity Reference View Widget, but neither worked (contact a is the author contact, b is the organisation, field_test_member..... is the organisation)

Am I heading into this the wrong way? Should I just build a webform and a node creation rule?

Comment: I was about to offer that final suggestion. You can make 'webform' apply to any 'content type' I believe, so it may work better to do that if that permits you to then pull the value of that field in as a field on to your node.

Comment: On a recent non-civi project I struggled to get Webform to create a node with Rules - there was a specific bug preventing it, and I ended up writing a custom module. Good luck though!

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems a bit off to me. Focussing just on the portion of it that retrieves the employers of the logged in user wouldn't you have something like:
Select employer.id, employer.display_name from
civicrm_contact employer inner join
civicrm_relationship r on r.contact_id_b=employer.id
where r.contact_id_a=$current_contact_id limit 0,10;

(If your user isn't logged in, then I would just drop the where clause to populate the select widget with all employer orgs.)

IIRC the employer is the b contact for the relationship, not the a - might want to check that.

Comment: Contact A is set as the logged in user as far as I can see from the fields in the displays. I placed organisation name as a field so that I could re-write Contact ID B to display the name of the organisation as I have not found a "Contact B display Name" field at all under CiviCRM Relationships or Contacts. Our original development was built using a custom organisation other than employer (as the users were not employees)